# Read imageView Width and Height inside adapter at run time

Tags: android

We need to identify the `imageView` Width or height inside `BaseAdapter`.The `ImageView` `Width` or `height` define `match-parent` in xml file. There is a way to identify the directly `width` and `heignt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   final ImageView v = holder.mainImage;
        v.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            itemHeight = v.getHeight();
            Log.d("Height", "" + itemHeight);
        }

    });
 }
```

is it this what you are looking for...or tell me what you are trying to do...mark it up if this helps..

Comment: Thanks for reply but this peace of code is not working because addOnPreDrawListener call when after adapter postion is 2 . Means after loop return this method call